# attempt to index a nil value in lua

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I've this code,

```
hook.Add( "PlayerSwitchWeapon", function( ply, oldWeapon, newWeapon )
    if (tostring(newWeapon) == tostring(hololink_swep) ) then
        print( "This weapon is speciall" .. newWeapon:GetClass() .. "." );
    end
end );
```

When I execute it, I get,

> Error(s), warning(s): lua5.3: source_file.lua:1: attempt to index a
>   nil value (global 'hook') stack traceback:    source_file.lua:1: in main
>   chunk     [C]: in ?

Comment: `hook` is nil, it says so right in the error message. My best guess is that `Hook` should be in uppercase instead.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - [docs](https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/hook/Add)

Comment: A script using gmod objects could be run only in the context of the game engine.  Your script will not work under pure Lua.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your scripts in a specific folder to make them run inside the games engine. I suggest you put them into `garrysmod/addons/YOURADDONNAME/lua/autorun/server or client`, the realm depends on what you want to do.
Where you need to place what is explained pretty good in the wiki under this [link](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Lua_Folder_Structure).